# Why the initialize function leading to activity crash?

Tags: android

I am trying to write an app simulating keyboard entry. There is a function initialize() in the activity. The function is used to initialize the UI. However, the function makes the activity crash. I am wondering why this would happen.`

```
private void initialize(){
        // initialize the UI;
        labelsInitialize();
        calculatePositionsAndLocations();
        drawKeyboard();

        // set the target directory name and file name
        directoryName = "Subject_" + subjectID + "_" +firstName + "_" + lastName;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
        resultFileName = "Day_" + dayNum + "_Keyboard_" + keyboardNum + "_" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".txt";

        // create an object of the File I/O wrapper class
        bufferedData = new ArrayList<>();

        // load the test phrases and display the first target phrase on the interface
        // loadTestCaseFile();
        TargetPhrase.setText(testPhrases.get(currentPhraseNum));
        TranscribedPhrase.setText("");

        // set the touch event listener on part of the layout;
        myKC = findViewById(R.id.keyboard_container);
        myKC.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    touchEventHandler(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }
                return true;
            }
```

This is the logcat:
2021-06-19 18:55:54.588 2639-31662/? E/DollieActivityManagerAdapter: HwActivityNotifierEx null uid
2021-06-19 18:55:54.588 1706-3380/? E/HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: invalid ActivityRecord, error.
2021-06-19 18:55:54.588 1706-3380/? E/HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: parse activity info error.
2021-06-19 18:55:54.597 2639-2814/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.example.magickeyboard/com.example.magickeyboard.Activities.KeyboardSelection state:20 fg:false mUid:10182
2021-06-19 18:55:54.598 2639-2814/? E/NetworkQoe: sendModemParaCollecEnable invalid defaultDataSlotId=-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.600 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: convertSubIdToSlotId failed, subId:0, slotId:-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.600 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: getDefaultDataSlotId failed, invalid slotId:-1, subId:0
2021-06-19 18:55:54.600 2639-2814/? E/BroadcastProxy: isDataOn failed, invalid slotId=-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.600 2639-2814/? E/SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
2021-06-19 18:55:54.600 2639-2814/? E/ScgQuickAddManager: uidInfo.isForeGroundUid() is false
2021-06-19 18:55:54.610 1706-2561/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: failed to find this proc.
2021-06-19 18:55:54.631 32060-32060/? E/e.magickeyboar: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-06-19 18:55:54.663 2639-3500/? E/Hicom_PolicyCenter: handleAppStarted. multipathPolicy is null
2021-06-19 18:55:54.695 1039-1050/? E/AwareLog: iawared: GetFileContent open /proc/32091/task/32093/cpuset fail errno(2)!
2021-06-19 18:55:54.703 32060-32095/com.example.magickeyboard E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@ec5eade
2021-06-19 18:55:54.783 2639-2814/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.example.magickeyboard/com.example.magickeyboard.Activities.DaySelection state:2 fg:true mUid:10182
2021-06-19 18:55:54.785 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: convertSubIdToSlotId failed, subId:0, slotId:-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.785 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: getDefaultDataSlotId failed, invalid slotId:-1, subId:0
2021-06-19 18:55:54.785 2639-2814/? E/NetworkQoe: sendModemParaCollecEnable invalid defaultDataSlotId=-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.786 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: convertSubIdToSlotId failed, subId:0, slotId:-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.786 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: getDefaultDataSlotId failed, invalid slotId:-1, subId:0
2021-06-19 18:55:54.786 2639-2814/? E/BroadcastProxy: isDataOn failed, invalid slotId=-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.787 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: convertSubIdToSlotId failed, subId:0, slotId:-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.787 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: getDefaultDataSlotId failed, invalid slotId:-1, subId:0
2021-06-19 18:55:54.787 2639-2814/? E/BroadcastProxy: isDataOn failed, invalid slotId=-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.788 2639-2814/? E/SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
2021-06-19 18:55:54.788 2639-2814/? E/ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :com.example.magickeyboard
2021-06-19 18:55:54.789 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: convertSubIdToSlotId failed, subId:0, slotId:-1
2021-06-19 18:55:54.789 2639-2814/? E/BoosterUtil: getDefaultDataSlotId failed, invalid slotId:-1, subId:0
2021-06-19 18:55:54.789 2639-2814/? E/BroadcastProxy: isDataOn failed, invalid slotId=-1

Comment: You'd better share android logcat message

Comment: Please post your logcat. Your logic code won't just enough to find a solution to your trouble. Also, try to improve the question explaining what you have tried so far.